# Docker 1.12-how to run a post deploy script after swarm deploy my service

Tags: docker, scripting, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm using Docker 1.12 (swarm mode) to deploy my services, now for some of the services I need to run a special script after the container is running.

How can I tell swarm to run the script every time the container is created?

For example, I have a service name: `redis` with **3 replicas**. Now I need swarm to run `myscript.sh` after every creation of a replica:

- `redis.replica1` and then `myscript.sh`
- `redis.replica2` and then `myscript.sh`
- etc.

The most important is that if `redis.replica1` is down and swarm automatically deploy a new replica: `redis.replica4`, or on scaling more replicas, it will run my script (`myscript.sh`) even after a successful first deployment:

- `redis.replica4` and then `myscript.sh`
- etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not run the script in your redis container?

Comment: I use project from docker hub, i dont want to build and maintenance my own (by creating dockerfile). I need a way to run scripts outside the containers...